# Get the issues mentioned in the merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

Is there an API in gitlab that can fetch the issues mentioned in the merge request? I keep looking at the documentation, but I can't find it.

I'd like to take advantage of this and try to automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Gitlab merge request API is what you need https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-issues-that-close-on-merge

You can get all the issues that would be closed by merging the provided merge request.

```
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/closes_issues
```

Example command:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/merge_requests/<merge_request_id>/closes_issues"
```

Comment: I haven't been able to verify this. thank you. :)